# eforms limit to width of textfield

Tags: forms

Is it possible to prevent that text is entered when the width of the textfield is reached?

So I know:

\FfDoNotScroll (disable the scrolling of long text, this limits the amount of
text that can be entered to the width of the text field provided...)

But this only seems to prevent vertical scrolling, right? I want to prohibit "prolonging" of a textfield.

This happens e.g. here:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{eforms}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcounter{linecounter}
\newcommand{\linie}[2]{
    \foreach \n in {1,...,#1}
{   \ifthenelse{\n=1}{\definePath{\ABC}{#2}}{\definePath{\ABC}{}}
    \stepcounter{linecounter}
    \textField[
    \Ff\FfDoNotSpellCheck
    \Ff\FfDoNotScroll
    \BC{0 0 0}
    \textColor{0 0 0}
    \textSize{12}
    \V{\ABC}
    \S{U}
    ]
    {\thelinecounter}{\textwidth}{1.5\baselineskip}

\vspace*{.3cm}
}
}

\begin{document}
\linie{3}{Wenn...}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Show a small complete example. That makes it much easier to test solutions.

Comment: To make myself more clear: I want to prevent that a user types more in the textfield than possible based on the width of the textfield. As of now the behaviour is that the textfield "horizontally scrolls over" when more text is entered.

Comment: Doesn't scroll for me. Which pdf viewer are you using?

Comment: Oh boy, it's again because of that viewer in Edge.